# Tkinter - how to dismiss border?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

Any chance to dismiss these borders in Tkinter while in fullscreen mode?
Running on raspberry pi (same in windows).

```
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18979647/8881141

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of widget border in Tk()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979647/how-to-get-rid-of-widget-border-in-tk)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is not highlightthickness

Comment: My _guess_ of your [mcve] runs borderless in `C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as tk; tk.TkVersion; import platform as pf; pf.platform()
8.6
'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'`

Comment: to run fullscreen use `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)`. See example [fullscreen](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/fullscreen/main.py)